# Docker run command to force restart only every 5 minutes

Tags: docker

My current command to run the container:

```
docker run -d -p 10000:3000 --restart=always --name metabase-prod metabase/metabase
```

However this one forces restart attempts too much. I only want for the restart attempt to happen every 5 minutes. How can achieve that?

Comment: If you were using Docker Compose, there's a way to set a restart delay. Don't think that you can change the restart delay otherwise.

Comment: I guess you have a dependency to another container that must be alive. You usually implement such a behavior in an `entrypoint.sh`. So I would build a custom image with my `entrypoint.sh` that retries every x mins. More information on [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [crontab](https://crontab.guru/) to schedule restart in case container is down.

```
docker ps|grep 'my_container'
```

will output if container is running.

```
5 * * * * /script_to_check_container_is_down_and_run
```

crontab config, will execute the script every 5 mins

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(docker ps|grep 'my_container'|wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
then
    docker start 'my_container'
fi
```

is a rudimentary example of script which can be in `script_to_check_container_is_down_and_run`